# msiexec.exe always running

Tags: windows, installation, msi

Seems like every time I go to install something it says that another installer is currently running.  And sure enough, if I check Task Manager, there is an *msiexec* process running.  It just says the command line is `C:\WINDOWS\systme32\msiexec.exe /V` and that it's started by `SYSTEM` user.  It seems to be associated with the msiserver service.

It doesn't seem to be running right after booting.  But it doesn't seem to take more than 10-15 minutes or so, and then it's there.  It's very mysterious to me.

Anyway, it seems to be blocking all my installs.  I say this because if I kill this msiexec.exe process, then I can usually proceed with the installation of other software.  And besides rebooting the computer and quickly running installing whatever I wanted to install before this mysterious msiexec.exe can launch, killing the process is currently my only other workaround -- but that's really annoying and shouldn't be required.

I don't know why this is happening.  I don't know what might be starting it, and I'm not sure how to fix it.  But it's really annoying and I'd like it if it would stop preventing me from installing software normally and so that I don't have to keep killing it before installing software.

Comment: Is this system managed by Config Manager?

Comment: @Davidw, No, the system is not managed by Config Manager.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if there's a failed install?

Comment: Is Windows Update corrupted?

Comment: @spacenomyous, I don't know.  Is there a command I can run that will tell me if Windows Update is corrupted?  Similarly is there a command I can run that will tell me if there is a failed install?